# If the system respects time-reversal symmetry, does the T-even anti-symmetric conductivity tensor indicate a dissipationless transport?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, transport

In [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.69.235206), the authors discuss the three response relations or Ohm's law for spin/charge transport. The first one is the spin Hall effect described by:
$$J_j^i=\sigma_{s}\epsilon_{ijk}E_k \tag{1},$$
where $J_j^i$ is the current of the $i$th component of the spin along
the direction $j$, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the totally antisymmetric tensor in
three dimensions and $E_k$ is the applied electric field. The authors argue that Eq.(1) offers a kind of dissipationless transport by:

> However, unlike Ohm’s law, this fundamental response equation Eq.(1) describes a
> purely topological and dissipationless spin current. It is important to note here that the spin current is even under the
> time-reversal operation $\mathcal{T}$. When the direction of the arrow of
> time is reversed, both the direction of the current and the
> spin are reversed and the spin current remains unchanged.
> Since both the spin current and the electric field in Eq. (1)
> are even under time reversal $\mathcal{T}$, the transport coefficient $\sigma_s$ is
> called “reactive” and can be purely nondissipative. This is in sharp contrast to Ohm’s law
> $$J_i=\sigma E_i$$
> relating the charge current $J_i$ to the electric field $E_i$. In this case,
> the charge current $J_i$ changes sign under time reversal $\mathcal{T}$,
> while the electric field is even under $\mathcal{T}$. Since Ohm’s law
> relates quantities of different symmetries under time reversal
> $\mathcal{T}$, the charge conductivity $\sigma$ breaks the time-reversal symmetry and describes the inevitable joule heating and dissipation.

The second one is the quantum Hall effect with the following Ohm's law:
$$J_i=\sigma_{H}\epsilon_{ij}E_j \tag{2}$$
where $\sigma_H \propto \vec{B}$ with $\vec{B}$ the magnetic field. The authors argue that:

> Quantum Hall current, which is transverse to the electric field and dissipationless, has a feature similar to Eq.
> (1), but the time-reversal symmetry is compensated by the
> external magnetic field.

The final case is:

> Dissipationless current without time-reversal symmetry breaking is extremely important and fundamental in solid-state physics, the most celebrated example
> of which is the superconducting current. It is described by
> the London equation,
> $$J_i=\rho_s A_i, \quad E_i=\partial_t A_i, \quad (e=m=c=1) \tag{3}$$
> where the current $J_i$ is related to the vector potential $A_i$ instead of the electric field. In the London equation, both $J_i$ and $A_i$ are odd under time reversal $\mathcal{T}$, therefore, the transport coefficient $\rho_s$ also called the superfluid density, describes the reversible and dissipationless flow of the supercurrent.

By studying the three cases, I have the following question:

**If the system respects time-reversal symmetry, does the T-even anti-symmetric conductivity tensor indicate a dissipationless transport?**

Comment: Please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been almost 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?